# Keep 2 columns next to each other in PDFMake?

Tags: pdfmake

I want to have a text `s.calculatedQuantity` and next to it an icon. But i want them to be always next to each other and not be separated. Sometimes when `s.setDescription` is long i have a bad result like in the image below. And i dont know why there is sometimes that space between the icon and the text `s.calculatedQuantity`. Can someone explain to me that ?

[image].

I Have my code like this :

```js
function generateSetDescription(s, picto) {
  return {
   columns: [
    {
     text: `${s.setDescription} - `,
     fillColor: '#000',
     color: '#FFF'
    },
    {
     text: `${s.calculatedQuantity}`,
     fillColor: '#000',
     color: '#FFF'
    },
    {
     image: icon,
     width: 10,
     height: 10,
     fillColor: '#000',
    },
   ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having seems to be caused by too long words (not text) normal text seems to wrap correctly when a blank space is found.

My suggestion is to programmatically break your 'very long words' adding a - in between.

something like this should work in your case

```
const text = veryLongTextWithLongWords;

const wrappedText = text.split(' ').map(word => {
  if(word.length > 80){
    return `${word.substr(0, 40)}-${word.substr(41)}
  }
  return word;
})

const columns = [
  { text: wrappedText }
]
```

[image]

You can test it out here
http://pdfmake.org/playground.html